# What's the difference between SpanWithInQuery and SpanContainingQuery in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am confused about the difference between these two queries. From the official document, my understanding is that both of these queries make a intersection of result Big and result Little. But if in this way, the final returned matches of these two are same.

Hope someone can give us an explanation of this, examples better.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the official documentation, `SpanContainingQuery` will return...

> ...matching spans from `big` that contain matches from `little`

whereas `SpanWithinQuery` will return...

> ...matching spans from `little` that are enclosed within `big`

In clear, the former will keep matches that **contain** another Spans, while the latter will keep matches that **are contained within** another Spans.

You can find a few usage examples of both in the [official Lucene test cases](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/53981795fd73e85aae1892c3c72344af7c57083a/lucene/core/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/TestSpanContainQuery.java).

Comment: Did this help ?

Comment: These basically are documents. I know little about Lucene. Some ES examples will help a lot. thanks anyway!

Comment: You can find examples in the ES documentation: [Span Within](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-within-query.html) and [Span Containing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-containing-query.html)

Comment: that's an example of the query, but not of the result, which would be necessary to understand what the query does